# Vue2 js and IE document mode (IE 11)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue2 application which runs perfectly in chrome. However, when I launch the site in IE 11, it gives a blank page. On further investigation, I observed the following - 
1. From developer tool Emulator tab, If I change the document type to Edge or 10, my solution works perfectly fine., and there is no error in console
2. If I change the document type back to 7 (default), the page becomes blank and  it gives three errors in console -  "SCRIPT1028 - Expected identifier, string or number"
For the script error mentioned in point 2, I have checked my code and removed any unwanted commas, if applicable, but that did not help much.
I am using axios in my code.

Note: I get these errors only from deployed code (in dev, SIT, or UAT box). When I run it locally, IE does not give any error because when I run it locally, the default document type is Edge. It is only when I run from server, the default document type takes 7.

I believe if I take care of the script errors I get, it should resolve my problem. However, I am not too sure how to solve the script error.
I am pretty new to Vue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!